# Move object up/down with swipe gesture

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-gesture

I'm trying to move an object between `max_height` and `min_height` value, I've found a piece of code and I tried to adapt it, but the object (`CardView`) move around full height of screen, and when I try to move the object reappears in another location before moving, I do not know how to adapt it to my needs, any ideas?

```
public interface OnLayoutCloseListener {
    void OnLayoutClosed();
}

enum Direction {
    UP_DOWN,
    LEFT_RIGHT,
    NONE
}
private Direction direction = Direction.NONE;
private int previousFingerPositionY;
private int previousFingerPositionX;
private int baseLayoutPosition;
private boolean isScrollingUp;
private boolean isLocked = false;
private OnLayoutCloseListener listener;

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    if (isLocked) {
        return false;
    } else {
        final int y = (int) ev.getRawY();
        final int x = (int) ev.getRawX();


        if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            previousFingerPositionX = x;
            previousFingerPositionY = y;

        } else if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {


            int diffY = y - previousFingerPositionY;
            int diffX = x - previousFingerPositionX;

            if (Math.abs(diffX) + 50 < Math.abs(diffY)) {
                return true;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    if (!isLocked) {

        final int y = (int) ev.getRawY();
        final int x = (int) ev.getRawX();

        if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            previousFingerPositionX = x;
            previousFingerPositionY = y;
            baseLayoutPosition = (int) this.getY();

        } else if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {


            int diffY = y - previousFingerPositionY;
            int diffX = x - previousFingerPositionX;

            if (direction == Direction.NONE) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    direction = Direction.LEFT_RIGHT;
                } else if (Math.abs(diffX) < Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    direction = Direction.UP_DOWN;
                } else {
                    direction = Direction.NONE;
                }
            }

            if (direction == Direction.UP_DOWN) {
                isScrollingUp = diffY <= 0;

                this.setY(baseLayoutPosition + diffY);
                requestLayout();
                return true;
            }

        } else if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            if (direction == Direction.UP_DOWN) {

                if (isScrollingUp) {

                    //Calculates height according to my needs
                    int max_height = height - (card.getHeight() + toolbar.getHeight());

                    if (Math.abs(this.getY()) > max_height) {

                        if (listener != null) {
                            listener.OnLayoutClosed();
                        }

                    }

                } else {

                    //Calculates height according to my needs
                    int min_height = height - ((int)(toolbar.getHeight() * 1.7));
                    if (Math.abs(this.getY()) > min_height) {
                        if (listener != null) {
                            listener.OnLayoutClosed();
                        }

                    }

                }

                ObjectAnimator positionAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(card, "y", this.getY(), 0);
                positionAnimator.setDuration(0);
                positionAnimator.start();

                direction = Direction.NONE;
                return true;
            }

            direction = Direction.NONE;
        }

        return true;

    }

    return false;
}

public void setOnLayoutCloseListener(OnLayoutCloseListener closeListener) {
    this.listener = closeListener;
}

public void lock() {
    isLocked = true;
}

public void unLock() {
    isLocked = false;
}
```

**UPDATE SOLUTION:**

Reset `LayoutParam` at any instance of card:

```
card.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Than use this code for scroll view between `min_height` and `max_height`

```
private int previousFingerPositionY;
private int previousFingerPositionX;
int min_height = 500;
int max_height = 100;
int pressedy;
int viewMariginY;

private boolean isLocked = false;
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (isLocked) {
        return false;
    } else {
        final int y = (int) ev.getRawY();
        final int x = (int) ev.getRawX();
        if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            previousFingerPositionX = x;
            previousFingerPositionY = y;
        } else if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            int diffY = y - previousFingerPositionY;
            int diffX = x - previousFingerPositionX;
            if (Math.abs(diffX) + 25 < Math.abs(diffY)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int currenty=(int) event.getRawY();
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) card.getLayoutParams();
    switch(event.getAction())
    {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            pressedy=currenty;
            viewMariginY=layoutParams.topMargin;
            break;


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
            int diffy=currenty-pressedy;
            int marginy=viewMariginY+diffy;
            layoutParams.topMargin=marginy;
            if(marginy >= max_height && marginy <= min_height)
            {
                ObjectAnimator positionAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(card, "y", this.getY(), marginy);
                positionAnimator.setDuration(0);
                positionAnimator.start();
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            int diffy2=currenty-pressedy;
            int marginy2=viewMariginY+diffy2;
            layoutParams.topMargin=marginy2;
            if(marginy2 >= max_height && marginy2 <= min_height)
            {
                ObjectAnimator positionAnimator1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(card, "y", this.getY(), marginy2);
                positionAnimator1.setDuration(0);
                positionAnimator1.start();
            }
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int pressedx,pressedy;
    int viewMariginX,viewMariginY;  

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int currentx=(int) event.getRawX();
    int currenty=(int) event.getRawY();


//get Layout Param of your cardView 

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

    switch(event.getAction())
    {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :

        pressedx=currentx;
        pressedy=currenty;

        viewMariginX=layoutParams.leftMargin;
        viewMariginY=layoutParams.topMargin;
        break;


    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE : 

        int diffx=currentx-pressedx;
        int diffy=currenty-pressedy;

        int marginx=viewMariginX+diffx;
        int marginy=viewMariginY+diffy;


        layoutParams.leftMargin=marginx;
        layoutParams.topMargin=marginy;     
        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);          
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP : 

        int diffx2=currentx-pressedx;
        int diffy2=currenty-pressedy;

        int marginx2=viewMariginX+diffx2;
        int marginy2=viewMariginY+diffy2;


        layoutParams.leftMargin=marginx2;
        layoutParams.topMargin=marginy2;            
        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);    
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Your reference is similar to what i have done few days ago.

It take difference of two postions and add them to the current View margin from left and from top.

You can retain View's Position by saving those margin values.

**NOTE**: You have to take care of your MAX and MIN Bounds

hope it helps you...

**UPDATE**: 
1)
Attach onTouchListners on you as many cardviews as you want

cardview.setOnTouchListener(this);
cardview1.setOnTouchListener(this);

OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
Called when a touch event is dispatched to a view. This allows listeners to get a chance to respond before the target view.

Specified by: onTouch(...) in OnTouchListener
Parameters:
v : The view the touch event has been dispatched to.
event : The MotionEvent object containing full information about the event.
by docs.

change your cardview in onTouch to v

From your question

FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();

ObjectAnimator positionAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "y", this.getY(), marginy);
            positionAnimator.setDuration(0);
            positionAnimator.start();

change further references in same method.

2) problem in setting bounds is simple Condition check just before changing the position.

and sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: It will modify margins of your card View if you dont want that just replace the param code with your translation code since you got the relative difference now..

Comment: i am little confused in your updated question between your first and last sentence. anyways i have updated my ans

Comment: onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)  use this method instead of onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) and by reset you mean please explain

Comment: with onTouch(..) doesn't work, by reset if using the method described above , I would to restore initial parameters... not this layoutParams.topMargin=marginy2;

Comment: I've found a solution, thank you very much for helping sir

Answer (score 0):

This animation:

```
ObjectAnimator positionAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(card, "y", this.getY(), 0);
```

Moves the view on the vertical axis from the `this.getY()` y position to 0 (the top of the screen).

I see you're setting some bounds `max_height` and `min_height`, but you're not using them in any way.

I'm not sure what you're requirements are but you can do something like this:

```
ObjectAnimator positionAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(card, "y", this.getY(), (Math.abs(this.getY() - min_height) < Math.abs(this.getY() - max_height))?min_height:max_height);
```

What this will do is to move the object to `min_height` or `max_height` based on which one is the closest.

The view seems to also be animated by this calls `this.setY(baseLayoutPosition + diffY); requestLayout();`, you will have to make sure that `baseLayoutPosition + diffY` is within the bounds, something like:

```
int amount = baseLayoutPosition + diffY;
this.setY(Math.min(max_height, Math.max(min_height, amount)));
```

Comment: yes but it move around full height of screen...I would between the min and max height, and start from min

Comment: @MicheleLacorte In that case, try: `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(card, "y", min_height, max_height);`

Comment: I've tried with both ObjectAnimator but nothing the CardView is blocked and not flowing it up nor down, remains stationary , or sometimes makes the shots in up/down